# instead of using drop_first=True, how can I set reference level for dummy coding in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, dummy-variable

I'm doing a logistic regression model in python using statsmodel. I use get_dummies to convert my categorical variables to dummy variables. How can I set reference level for dummy coding in pandas?

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [5,6,7,8], 'c': [9,10,11,12], 
     'colors': pd.Series(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True)
print(df)
```

When I set drop_first=True, 'blue' will be dropped. How can I set 'green' as the reference level for my dummy variable? (I want to keep 'blue' column and drop 'green' column instead)

Is it wrong if I set `drop_first=False` then drop 'green' column by doing `df.drop('green', axis=1)`?
I'm wondering if there's a method in pandas for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [formula api](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html). With the formula api you can provide a "formula string" that expresses your model. Under the hood, statsmodels uses [Patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to transform your data according to the formula string.

To set the reference level in the formula string you use a "Treatment".

```
import statsmodel.formula.api as smf

log_reg = smf.logit("y ~ C(colors, Treatment(reference='green'))", data=df)
```

More options [here](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html) and [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/contrasts.html).

You can also work with Patsy outside of statsmodels if you want to inspect or test the transformations.